# Delete random columns that contain a specific value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have server logs that need to be filtered and then turned into single alerts - each log becomes one alert. I first filter the values I need from a massive json file, wherein each becomes a list of values. If the key in the json file contains no value, I then add a ' - '. See the sample lists below:

```
#Not all fields contain data, and thus are replaced with a -
timestamp_list = ['07/11/2023','07/10/2023','07/09/2023']
username_list = ['jsmith','arossi',' - ']
host_list = ['10.10.1.100',' - ','10.10.1.300']
file_path_list = ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop','C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop',' - ']
account_name_list = ['smith','rossi',' - ']
```

Next, I create a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

def dataframe():
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':timestamp_list,'Username':username_list,"Host":host_list,
                     'FilePath':file_path_list,'AccountName':account_name_list,})
    #Group Columns
    df_sum = df.groupby(['Timestamp','Username','Host','FilePath','AccountName']) \
        .agg(Detections = ("Timestamp", len)) \
        .reset_index()
    
    df_final = pd.DataFrame(df_sum,columns=['Timestamp','Username','Host','FilePath','AccountName'])
    return df_final
final = dataframe()
print(final)
```

Output:

```
    Timestamp Username         Host               FilePath AccountName
0  07/09/2023       -   10.10.1.300                     -           -
1  07/10/2023   arossi           -   C:\Users\user\Desktop       rossi
2  07/11/2023   jsmith  10.10.1.100  C:\Users\user\Desktop       smith
```

Because I need to create individual files for each event, I now throw each row in the dataframe above (each is an event) into a list so I can iterate over it later.

```
#Add events to list
def add_to_list():
    Signal_list = []
    signal_list = []
    for row in final.itertuples():
        if row not in signal_list:
            signal_list = [row.Timestamp,row.Username,row.Host,row.FilePath,row.AccountName]
            Signal_list.append(signal_list)
    return Signal_list
events_list = add_to_list()
print(events_list)
```

Output:

```
[['07/09/2023', ' - ', '10.10.1.300', ' - ', ' - '], ['07/10/2023', 'arossi', ' - ', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop', 'rossi'], ['07/11/2023', 'jsmith', '10.10.1.100', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop', 'smith']]
```

Now, I sort the items in the list:

```
#sort list items
def sort_list_items():
    count = Counter(map(tuple,events_list))
    return count
event_dict = sort_list_items()
print(event_dict)
```

Output:

```
Counter({('07/09/2023', ' - ', '10.10.1.300', ' - ', ' - '): 1, ('07/10/2023', 'arossi', ' - ', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop', 'rossi'): 1, ('07/11/2023', 'jsmith', '10.10.1.100', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop', 'smith'): 1})
```

Finally, I iterate over the dict looking for rows that contain ' - '. If they do, the entire column should be dropped. And here is where the problem is. The output is not what it should be.

```
def create_html_files(event_dict):
    html_file = []
    count = 0
    #Turn rows into columns
    for items in list(event_dict):
        df = pd.DataFrame(items)
        new_df = df.transpose()
        new_df.columns = ['Timestamp','Username','Host','FilePath','AccountName']
    
        #Delete columns whose row values are -
        for column in new_df.columns:
        # Check if the specific value is present in the column
            if new_df[column].eq(' - ').any():
                # Delete the column
                new_df.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)

                html_file.append(new_df.to_html())
                count +=1
                with open(f'event{count}.html','w') as wf:
                    wf.write(html_file[-1])
    return html_file
create_html_files(event_dict)
```

Current Output from each html file:

File 1

```
Timestamp   Host         FilePath  AccountName
07/09/2023  10.10.1.300  -         -
```

File 2

```
Timestamp   Host         AccountName
07/09/2023  10.10.1.300  -
```

File 3

```
Timestamp   Host
07/09/2023  10.10.1.300
```

File 4

```
Timestamp   Username   FilePath               AccountName
07/10/2023  arossi     C:\Users\user\Desktop  rossi
```

I don't understand why there's a fourth file since there are only 3 events.

Expected Output:

File 1

```
Timestamp  Host
07/09/2023 10.10.1.300
```

File 2

```
Timestamp  Username  FilePath               AccountName
07/10/2023   arossi  C:\Users\user\Desktop  rossi
```

File 3

```
Timestamp  Username         Host               FilePath AccountName
07/11/2023   jsmith  10.10.1.100  C:\Users\user\Desktop       smith
```

In sum, the point is to remove the ' - ' from the final dataframe before they get transformed into html files. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and hope you can help out. I also know that the way I'm doing it may not be optimal, so you're welcome to streamline the code or modify it as you want as long as I get the desired output. Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Comment: I think it would help if the question had a lot less code and pointed out only the part where the problem is. It's a bit hard to navigate right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found where the problem is, although it wasn't too easy.

In this snippet from your question look at when you're appending your new_df to the final list `html_file.append(new_df.to_html())`:

```
def create_html_files(event_dict):
    html_file = []
    count = 0
    #Turn rows into columns
    for items in list(event_dict):
        df = pd.DataFrame(items)
        new_df = df.transpose()
        new_df.columns = ['Timestamp','Username','Host','FilePath','AccountName']
    
        #Delete columns whose row values are -
        for column in new_df.columns:
        # Check if the specific value is present in the column
            if new_df[column].eq(' - ').any():
                # Delete the column
                new_df.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)

                html_file.append(new_df.to_html())
                count +=1
                with open(f'event{count}.html','w') as wf:
                    wf.write(html_file[-1])
    return html_file
create_html_files(event_dict)
```

It happens for each `df` each time the condition `if new_df[column].eq(' - ').any()` passes, i. e. each time you've found a column with `" - "`. In some of your input examples there are multiple such columns - therefore the strange number of files.

Instead, write the final version of `new_df` only once after checking all the columns

```
def create_html_files(event_dict):
    html_file = []
    count = 0
    #Turn rows into columns
    for items in list(event_dict):
        df = pd.DataFrame(items)
        new_df = df.transpose()
        new_df.columns = ['Timestamp','Username','Host','FilePath','AccountName']
    
        #Delete columns whose row values are -
        for column in new_df.columns:
        # Check if the specific value is present in the column
            if new_df[column].eq(' - ').any():
                # Delete the column
                new_df.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)

        # CORRECTED INDENTATION STARTS HERE
        html_file.append(new_df.to_html())
        count +=1
        with open(f'event{count}.html','w') as wf:
            wf.write(html_file[-1])
    return html_file
create_html_files(event_dict)
```

Comment: It worked well . Thanks a lot for taking the time to help!